# 'not recognized as an internal or external command' Running batch from Java

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying to run this 'gzip.bat'. what it does is zips all files in the directory it's located in. 'gzip.exe' is in the same directory.

```
@echo off
ren *.dat *.
gzip *.
pause
```

It runs perfectly fine when I run it from windows explorer.

But when I try to run it from Java, I get the error:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
'gzip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here is the Java code I am using:

```
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process p1 = runtime.exec("cmd /c start .\\data\\mapmaker\\gzipdir\\gzip.bat");

            InputStream is = p1.getInputStream();
            int i = 0;
            while( (i = is.read() ) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char)i);
            }
        } catch(IOException ioException) {
            System.out.println(ioException.getMessage() );
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You assume the wrong "current" directory when specifying the name of the batch file. It varies depending on how to start your application.

If run from an IDE, it is most likely the project folder.

If you run your Java application from a command line, then it is obvious (the current folder).

Change the path (`.\\data\\mapmaker\\gzipdir\\gzip.bat`) to an absolute path and it will work. Or specify the "working directory" in the run configuration of your IDE when you start it from there.

Also do not name your batch file after another executable which you call from the batch (`gzip.bat`, `gzip.exe`).

Comment: have changed it to


    Process p1 = runtime.exec("cmd /c start \"M:\\Workspace\\Client Tools\\data\\mapmaker\\gzipdir\\gzip.bat\"");

and it still does not work.